# Wire regular outlet from this 3-wired installation?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I had posted this question before, but never received an answer, so I deleted it and reposted a more complete question.

These are the three wires that go into a 240v Stiebel Eltron DHC 6-2 Electric Tankless Water Heater. Even though it's 240v, one of the things the electrician told me when he installed it was that the heater wouldn’t heat the water as well because the existing connection’s 120v. The breaker is two-pole.

With that wiring I want to install a regular outlet from this installation. This is the link to the [Leviton outlet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Residential-Grade-Grounding-Duplex-Outlet-White-R52-05320-00W/202066670?) I'll be buying at home depot.

Three wires go into the heater, but I'm not sure what the 3rd wire is (the one without the plastic cover)

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: First the double pole breaker how many amps is it? 20, 30 ? How many wires are connected to the double pole breaker? 1 or 2 ? The question can not be answered with out this info. If a 20 amp and only 1 wire connected to the breaker it would be electrically possible but possibly a code violation as the water heater is two large ( the size would need to be calculated based on 120v). If a 30 amp breaker as most on demand are you can’t do it because the breaker size is two large(20 amp max for receptacles). if both wires are on the breaker can’t do it no neutral. So you can see not likely.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the breaker panel? That would answer a lot of little questions about what you actually have.

Comment: Does the water heater work *at all*, does it make the water even tepid compared to cold?  Try slowing the flow rate down to under 0.5 GPM... does it heat water adequately at that point?

Comment: FYI, instead of deleting/reposting, you could [edit] the question to add the missing details or even completely change it (if there weren't already answers). This will bump it back to the top of the list so people will see it again. You could even add a bounty which temps some people to answer for the points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The water heater has two 120v wires plus a ground(the bare wire) equals a 240v circuit.

The breaker that protects it is at least 30amp or more, your outlet is for only 15amp circuits, needs a 15 amp breaker.  Also those wires will not fit onto a 15 or 20 amp outlet/device, they are too big.

The outlet also needs a neutral wire which you don't have.  To use the outlet you need a 15amp breaker(no more), a length of 14 gauge cable/wire with a hot, a neutral, and a ground wire or metal conduit.You could possibly go to a 20amp breaker and 12 gauge wire, but I think you need a 20 amp outlet if just the one.

The circuit for the heater is deem to a dedicated circuit(just for one device, the heater), no adding outlets to it.

If an electrician installed it, it must have 10 gauge wire and at least a 25 or 30 amp breaker delivering 240volts, or he could lose his licence.  If someone just checked it and said it was only using 120volts, then it should be done to code or you are wasting money for the heater and electricity.

Comment: I did not look up the receptacle, but the op mentioned running the heater at 120v , but still doubtful on 120v the op mentioned the heater was set up on.  Or it would not heat as well on 120v

Comment: @EdBeal  The receptacle is just your ordinary household one.  The heater Mins call for 25amps and 10guage at 240v(manufacturers instructions)

Comment: If fed with 120v instead of 240 the power would be inline with a residential receptacle but at aprox 1/4 the flow rate for the same rise in temp. Electricians get asked to go to a lower voltage on occasion and at that point it would not require 10 awg ,,, etc

Answer (score 1):

If it's 240v, you'll need to do some work in the panel. You'll need to pick up a 20 amp single pole breaker and a blank insert from the hardware store.

First, SHUT OFF YOUR MAIN BREAKER BEFORE OPENING THE PANEL.

Locate the 2 pole breaker in the panel for your water heater circuit. You'll notice both the black and white wires go the breaker. Take the white wire off the breaker and put it on the neutral bar to the right of the breakers (sometimes it's at the bottom or top). Then take the black wire off bad put it on your new 20 amp breaker. The bare copper wire is the ground and should stay where it's at (hopefully on the ground or neutral bar).

Now put the cover back on and put the blank insert in the open space that's missing a breaker.

You now have a 120v 20amp circuit. If your new outlet is going to be in the basement, it needs to be a [GFCI receptacle](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Self-Test-SmartlockPro-Slim-Duplex-GFCI-Outlet-White-R12-GFNT2-0RW/205996739).